# Remove class when bottom of element goes past point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a `class` to an element when the user scrolls past a certain point and then remove the same `class` when the bottom of the element has passed another point on the page.

I've got the first part working (adding class when `scrollTop` is greater than the top position of another element) but I'm having trouble removing the class further on - I can successfully remove the class, but then as my function occurs on scroll it's constantly checking the positioning, which means the functionality goes a bit haywire, with the `class` being added/removed on each scroll.

Please find my JS and a JSFiddle link below:

```
var top = jQuery(".lineTop").offset().top;

var lineTopTop = top + jQuery(".lineTop").height();

jQuery(window).on("scroll", function () {

    var stickablePosition = jQuery(".stickable").offset().top + jQuery(".stickable").height();

    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > top ) {

        jQuery(".stickable").addClass("sticky");

        if ( stickablePosition > lineTopTop ) {
            jQuery(".stickable").removeClass("sticky");
        };

    } else if ( top > jQuery(window).scrollTop() ) {
        jQuery(".stickable").removeClass("sticky");

    };

});
```

Here's my work so far: http://jsfiddle.net/nimaek/0wefgutq/9/

How do I make it so that the `sticky` class is never present when it would push the bottom of `stickable` below the bottom of `lineTop`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've worked it out. I just moved my stickablePosition variable inside the if statement.

```
jQuery(window).on("scroll", function () {

    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > top ) {

        jQuery(".stickable").addClass("sticky");

    var stickablePosition = jQuery(".stickable").offset().top + jQuery(".stickable").height();

        if ( stickablePosition > lineTopTop ) {
            jQuery(".stickable").removeClass("sticky");
        };

    } else if ( top > jQuery(window).scrollTop() ) {
        jQuery(".stickable").removeClass("sticky");

    };

});
```

Updated version at: http://jsfiddle.net/nimaek/0wefgutq/10/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for a deboucer. This function allows you to execute one time the function on scroll event, and not tons of executions in every scroll. You can use debouce function from David Walsh:

```
    function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout;
        return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    };
```

Use:

```
    var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {
        // All the taxing stuff you do
    }, 250);

    window.addEventListener('resize', myEfficientFn);
```

More information:

http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function